# How to get values from more than one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, javascript-objects, cypress

I am trying to write a test in cypress, I am connected to the db and have a created a selectQuery to select marketIds from DB.  Right now the values are shown below and I am able to get the first array's values but not the 2nd or 3rd arrays values.

example arrays below

```
{id: 1, name: apple},
{id: 2, name: pear},
{id: 3, name: kiwi}
```

code

```
  before(() => {
    cy.task('queryDb', selectMarketQuery).then(function (marketId) {
      const market = marketId;
      const values = Object.values(market[0]);
      const keys = Object.keys(market[0]);
      let result = {};
      let index = 0;
      keys.forEach(() => {
        result[keys[index]] = values[index];
        index++;
      });
      cy.log(result.name);
    });
  });
```

The result I get is apple.  How do I get all the names and not just the first one?

Comment: what is marketId structure ?

Comment: This looks like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and you are doing some strange things in your callback. What is your expected output?

Comment: @PedroBezanilla the marketId is just what one of the columns in the Db is called

Comment: @pilchard so I have two columns in the db - market_id and name.  I am able to get the first value in the name column but not the rest and same with market_id.  I want to find a way to get all the values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `marketId` is an array of the three objects you listed, then all you need is a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call to return a new array of just the `name` properties.

```
const names = marketId.map(({ name }) => name);
```

(Here using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access the `name` property in the passed arguments of the `map()` callback)

```js
const marketId = [
  { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
  { id: 2, name: 'pear' },
  { id: 3, name: 'kiwi' }
];

const names = marketId.map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(names);
```

---

But it looks like you are actually looking to return an object with properties grouped by key. ie:

```
const result = {
  id: [1, 2, 3],
  name: ['apple', 'pear', 'kiwi']
}
```

In this case you can use a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call to iterate over the array and then iterate over [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each object to group them by `key` in the accumulator.

```js
const marketId = [
  { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
  { id: 2, name: 'pear' },
  { id: 3, name: 'kiwi' }
];

const result = marketId.reduce((acc, product) => {
  Object.keys(product).forEach(key =>
    (acc[key] = acc[key] || []).push(product[key]));
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
```